# Adding element to a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, random

I'm relatively new here, so please tell me if there is anything I should know or any mistakes I am making manner wise!

I am trying to add things onto a dictionary through random choice, but my code doesn't seem to work!

The file:
sports.txt

```
Soccer, Joshua
Lacrosse, Naome Lee
Soccer, Kat Valentine
Basketball, Huong
Tennis, Sunny
Basketball, Freddie Lacer
```

my code so far:

```
def sportFileOpen():

    sportFile = open("sport.txt")
    readfile = sportFile.readlines()
    sportFile.close()
    return(readfile)


def sportCreateDict(sportFile):

    sportDict = {}

    for lines in sportFile:
        (sport, name) = lines.split(",")

        if sport in sportDict:
            sportDict[sport].append(name.strip())

        else:
            sportDict[sport] = [name.strip()]


    return(sportDict)



def sportRandomPick(name, sport, sportDict):


    if sport in sportDict:

        ransport = random.choice(sportDict.keys())

        sportDict[ransport].append(name)


        print(name, "has been sorted into", ransport)


def main():

    sportFile = sportFileOpen()

    sportDict = sportCreateDict(sportFile)


    name = input("Enter the name: ")

    preferredSport = input("Which sport do they want? ")

    sportRandomPick(name, preferredSport, sportDict)


main()
```

I am trying to allow a user to input their name and preferred group of sport, and whatever sport they prefer will have a higher chance of being randomly picked then the others (for example if Jason chooses soccer his chances of getting in soccer may double).

I don't expect anyone to write code for me, I know it's time consuming and you have better things to do! But can anyone maybe explain to me how I would go about doing this? I understand how to make random choices but I don't know how I would "double" the chances.

Also I keep getting this error when running my code: `NameError: global name 'random' is not defined`

I thought I was doing that part right but now i'm stuck. Can anyone give their two cents on this?

Comment: You need to import the random module. Just add this to the top of your code: `import random`. That'll take care of the error anyway.

Comment: ohhh I see! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def sportRandomPick(name, sport, sportDict):
    if sport in sportDict:
        ransport = random.choice(list(sportDict.keys()) + [sport]) # list of sports will contain preferred sport twice.

        sportDict[ransport].append(name)

        print(name, "has been sorted into", ransport)
```

This will increase chances of preferred sport to be picked by 2.

And don't forget to `import random`

Comment: Thanks explaining how to do that! I will now customize it to fit my needs!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are trying to use `random.choice` from [python random.choice](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/random.html#random.choice)

you need to make sure it is imported at the top of your file:

`import random`

```
def sportRandomPick(name, sport, sportDict):


    if sport in sportDict:

        ransport = random.choice(sportDict.keys())

        sportDict[ransport].append(name)


        print(name, "has been sorted into", ransport)
```

Comment: thank you for pointing that out! I completely forgot about that!